# Where do I put a downloaded module on a USB?

Tags: python, module, usb

So I am currently on a school computer that wipes all changes whenever it's turned off. I decided to copy the entire python34 library onto my external hard drive so I can install Python when I get back home, and I'm trying to write a program that uses a module that fails to import whenever I try. (The specific module is called [Colour.](https://pypi.org/project/colour/)) Where should I put the colour.py file so I can import it?

Comment: "I decided to copy the entire python34 library onto my external hard drive so I can install Python when I get back home" - that is not a safe way to install Python. Why not use the [actual installer](https://www.python.org/downloads/)?

Comment: What do you mean by "not safe?" Like is it going to get corrupted or something?

Comment: Among other problems, it's not going to perform any parts of Python setup that aren't just "plunk these files here", and the stuff you copied could be dependent on machine details or other things that aren't part of that folder.

Comment: For example, if you're on Windows, you won't get the file associations for `.py` and `.pyw` files, you won't get the `py` launcher program, you will get `python` and `pip` but they won't be added to your PATH, you won't get the start menu entries, …

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I found the answer. I just put it in the same folder as the code I was writing (specifically E:/Python34/Doc, which is probably not where it's meant to go). I won't archive the question though, don't worry future people